# Iron Router Router.go query string encoding

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to preserve a user's filter in an url's query string.

I've tried

```
Router.go('Channel', { channelId: channelId }, { query: "filter=" + encodeURIComponent(filterText) });
```

and

```
Router.go('/channel/' + channelId + "?filter=" + encodeURIComponent(filterText) );
```

to no avail.

If the user type Testing++ in the filter, the brower's url is http://localhost:3000/channel/someChannel?filter=Testing%2B%2B (correct), but the route's subscriptions function find this.params.query.filter as "Testing  ", no pluses (incorrect).

Ideas?

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1088) is the relevant issue.

Comment: I think you are right it looks like it's only a problem with +s

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and I'm pretty sure this is a bug with IR. I'll add my thoughts on the correct implementation to the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a bug with [iron-url](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-url), where `'%2B'` would decode to `' '` rather than to `'+'`.

I added a fix for it [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-url/commit/e373a06a7522881d8b8ee17a4879baffe9752418), and it should be available in the next version.